# Fill form values on external website using Selenium?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a ASP.Net application .When user clicks a link, his username and password for a third party website should auto-populate to that website.

I have seen Selenium web drivers can do this, but only on the local machine(server).
Is it possible to automate this on client browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can do this at client side that will be security issue then. Any way once you open the third party website on a click from your website either that new website loads independently or loads inside a iFrame inside your application depending upon your inmplementation in both cases you can not access anything in the site using the Javascript or something else. And Selenium is not at all possible as it is Java you can not run it in a clients machine.

Comment: Thanks, have you seen such functionality used somewhere or can you think of some way to do this?

Comment: Nope. Never seen such a requirement. Its a security issue. You can not do it at client side.